# Python as a framework under macOS

Tags: python, macos

I used the following command to install Python on my macOS

```
PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework" pyenv install -v 3.6.7
```

After the installation I got two executables of Python:

1. `/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/env/bin/python` which is a symbolic link to `/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.7/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python`, which's another symbolic link to `python3.6 (size: 9.4K)` in the same directory.
2. `/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.7/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python (size: 8.8K)`

However, if I execute `/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/env/bin/python` in the terminal, I will get `/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.7/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python` in `ps -ef`, which is a bit strange to me.

What are the relations between this two executables?

Thanks.

---

P.S.

The question comes from [here](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1481#issuecomment-467338358) when I'm using `Jedi` in some virtual env. You don't have to read it.